# Extract html element visually

Tags: c#, html, css, extract

Hi there this is my first question on stackoverflow so be nice.

I want to extract a html element but not only the element it should keep it's styles and functionality. So I tought of something like to select the wanted html element and then remove all remove every style from all other elements. What I'm asking is:

1. What things I do have **to remove**?

   - Obviously I have to remove all **styling attributes** from the parent elements, like **height**, **width**, **backgroundColor**, ...
   - In addition to that, **class** and **id tag**, cause they can get styling from css or somenthing like that *(can this effect the child element I want to exctract in a way that somethings missing?)*
   - And I've to remove all the contents of the other parent elements *(something speaks agains remove all parent elemens except script tags?)*
   - Remove all other element tress that are not a parent or child of the selected one
2. What things I can **not remove**?

   - Skript tags i shouldn't remove cause so I can lose functionality
   - Also I shouldnt remove Html tag body tag to keep kind of valid Html

After keeping and removing all wanted and unwanted stuff, I want only the selected element with it's content and child element's. If the selected element is a form or contains a form the form should work 100%.

Can you help me complete this list and some ideas what else is to consider beside html?

Thanks!

I try to this with C# mshtml/agilitypack but this souldn't be that relevant.

So that I can display a single(selected) html element in my webbrowser but keep it's funktions.

Comment: seems like this would be easier to do through a different route... such as creating a page that would get a url and selector parameter to load the elements in and only display them.. i dunno.. I can't see the big picture on why you are trying to do such a complex operation. I didn't downvote, though

Comment: First thank you for your awnser i added two lines to my question :). I'm not sure I understand you right, but I tried to get only the selected html element and present it on a new site, but that resultet in pure text. So i figured it is a better way to reduce the given site in a way everything that's not wanted gets remove so javascript funktions and everything that the extracted element may need's stay there.

Comment: honestly. I do not think that there is any simple solution to this. The scope is way too broad and your requirements are nearly impossible to meet without VERY specific code and very heavy processing on the client. Personally, I would say that this approach is unrealistic and that either the approach or the requirements would have to change before I could start working on it as my own project. As an outside source, I wouldn't touch this. Sorry. :/

Comment: I thank you but this sould be the easy part but if i got some results I'll post them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with some css it's quite simple! :)

Only set the visibility attribute. I think it is enough to set the highest parent's visiblity to collapse and the element you want to be visible you set to visible.

Maybe you have to set the visibility of all parent's to collapse. Maybe someone can give some imformation, am I right to assume that elements inhert there visiblity from parents except a visibility is set than this one is taken?

What ever this is the answer set parents set the parent's visibility to collapse and the child you want visible gets visible.